# How to delete a row in html table and reset key every row to default [0,1,2 ...]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with every row is a multidimensional array, with row name like ***name="product[key][order]"***
The key have default value is in ascending order (0,1,2,3...)
Whenever I click delete button each a row, I want to all key values in table are reset to default value but I dont know how to do?

It like table have rows got name like: name="product[1][name]", name="product[2][name]", name="product[3][name]".

### If I delete row get name="product[2][name]", I want the third row change the key from 3 to 2, etc...

Update question:

I have a problem when try to set key to the hidden input.I dont know How to set the key value for hidden input like

```
<input type=hidden name="products['+i+'][id]">
```

Anyone help me plz?

Table like
    https://jsfiddle.net/soulcrys/eydx7dn0

```
<table id="list">
  <tr>
<input type="hidden" maxlength="2" id="id" name="product[1][id]" value="" />
    <td>
      <input type="text" maxlength="2" id="display_order" name="product[1][order]" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="name" name="product[1][name]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add_more" />
```

---

```
   $('#add_more').click(function() {
  var currentLength = $('#list tr').length + 1;
  var htmldata = '<tr>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="order" name="product[' + currentLength + '][order]" value="' + currentLength + ' " />' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="name" name="product[' + currentLength + '][name]" value="" />' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete">' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '</tr>';
  $("#list").append(htmldata);
})

$(document).on('click','.deleteBtn',function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  var i=1;
  var j = 1;
  $('tr td input[type="text"]').each(function(index){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    if(id == 'order')
    {
      $(this).attr('name','products['+i+'][order]')
      $(this).val(i);
    }else if(id == 'name')
    {
      $(this).attr('name','products['+i+'][name]')
    }

    if(j == 2)
    {
      j = 1;
      i++;
    }else{
        j++;
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: `reset to default value` what is this default value you speak of?

Comment: by the way, your "add_more" click function will add input's with duplicated id's (i.e. `order` and `name`) - ID's *should* be unique within a HTML page, so you may want to fix that too

Comment: The key have default value is in ascending order (0,1,2,3...), or (1,2,3,4 ...). It like name="product[1][name]", name="product[2][name]", name="product[3][name]", If i delete row get name="product[2][name]", I want the third row change the key from 3 to 2, etc...

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajneeshrai83/accessing-item-index-in-foreach-binding-in-knockout/ this may solve your purpose.

full reference - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: so, is it 0,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4? you seem to want to start at 1 not 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to reset your ids

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eydx7dn0/7/

```
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  var currentLength = $('#list tr').length + 1;
  var htmldata = '<tr>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="order" name="product[' + currentLength + '][order]" value="' + currentLength + ' " />' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="text" maxlength="2" id="name" name="product[' + currentLength + '][name]" value="" />' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '<td>' + '<input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete">' + '</td>';
  htmldata += '</tr>';
  $("#list").append(htmldata);
})

$(document).on('click','.deleteBtn',function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  var i=1;
  var j = 1;
  $('tr td input[type="text"]').each(function(index){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    if(id == 'order' || id == 'display_order')
    {
      $(this).attr('name','products['+i+'][order]')
      $(this).val(i);
    }else if(id == 'name')
    {
      $(this).attr('name','products['+i+'][name]')
    }

    if(j == 2)
    {
      j = 1;
      i++;
    }else{
        j++;
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: It work, thank you !!! But I have one more question: How to set this key value for hidden input like <input type=hidden name="products['+i+'][id]"> ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @sabbirspi addresses one potential issue, but to answer the **actual** question (and shamelessly borrowing his first line of code)

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    $('#list tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(unused, input) {
            this.name = this.name.replace(/^(product\[)\d+(\].*)$/, function(match, p1, p2) {
                return p1 + (index + 1) + p2;
            });
            if(this.name.indexOf('[order]') > 0) {
                this.value = index + 1;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to work on live. change this code and maybe solve

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function() {


$(this).closest('tr').remove();

})
```

Comment: how will that change the value's in the name?